# How can I request the default favicon using Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, favicon

Given a domain, how can I request the default favicon using Node? The default favicon location is at `domain/favicon.ico` Can I use a simple `https.get()`? There seem to be at least [5 native ways](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html) to do this?

So far the first method does not work. I get `ERR_INVALID_DOMAIN_NAME` for this code:

```
const https = require('https');
const url = 'imdb.com/favicon.io';


https.get(url, (resp) => {
  let data = '';
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });
  resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

If I change the URL to `https://imdb.com/favicon.ico` I get

```
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.imdb.com/favicon.ico">here</a>.</p>
```

If I change the URL to `https://www.imdb.com/favicon.ico` I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/favicon-2165806970">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Finally if I change the URL to `https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/favicon-2165806970` I get what looks like a blob or binary file or image.

How can I do this programmatically?

If I recall PHP had a method that knew how to follow the "redirects", but what about Node?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow-redirects

Comment: `const url = 'imdb.com/favicon.io';` -- this is not an [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax). It misses the `scheme:` part (and the `host` part is incomplete).

Answer (score 3):

> The default favicon location is at `domain/favicon.ico`

he default favicon *path* is `/favicon.ico`, but you need an absolute URL (`schema://host/path`) in order to make a request.

> How can I do this programmatically?

If using core nodejs you need to manually follow the redirects via `response.headers['location']`, in some sort of recursive callback arrangement.  Alternatively you could use the modules [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or [`follow-redirects`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow-redirects).

> I get what looks like a blob or binary file or image.

Indeed, that's the image. As you can see from `response.headers['content-type']` it is in the `image/x-icon` format, also known as [ICO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)), as expected for a file called `favicon.ico`.

> data += chunk

Note that because you're concatenating with strings instead of buffers, this will cause image corruption in current NodeJS versions. It tries to treat the binary data as UTF-8, replacing unknown sequences. Instead you presumably just want to pipe to an `fs.WriteStream`.